# JodaTime - how to parse ISO 8601 time string into DateTime?

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime, iso, datetime-parsing

i have the string with time in the following format:

```
2016-01-07T08:00:00+00:00
```

When i trying to parse string using following method.

```
public static DateTime getDateTimeObject(String dateTime) {
        //DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(PATTERN);
        //DateTime dateTimeObj = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(dateTime);
        Logger.d(dateTime);
        DateTime dateTimeObj = null;
        try {
            dateTimeObj = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().parseDateTime(dateTime);
            return dateTimeObj;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e(e.getMessage());
        }
        return dateTimeObj;
    }
```

I always get following exception.

```
Invalid format: "2016-01-07T08:00:00+00:00" is malformed at "+00:00"
```

How can i parse string in ISO format to get valid DateTime object?

Comment: did you try `dateTimeObj = DateTime.parse(dateTime);`?

Comment: FYI, the Joda-Time project is in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes, in this case [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). Example: `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2016-01-07T08:00:00+00:00" )`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your value doesn't have a milliseconds component, so you want [`ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeNoMillis--):

> Returns a formatter that combines a full date and time without millis, separated by a 'T' (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ).

The [`dateTime()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTime--) method returns a formatter with a format of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ` which your string doesn't comply with.